# Output sqlaudit File Results to Text File - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Have a stored procedure that is suppose to retrieve results back from a .sqlaudit file.

From the results, I want to be able to transfer it to a .txt file.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]

@LoginName      VARCHAR(100),
@EventStartTime DATETIME 

AS

DECLARE @BCPSQL NVARCHAR(1000)

BEGIN

    SET @BCPSQL = 'BCP "SELECT * FROM fn_get_audit_file(''R:\Audit\*'', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
                            WHERE session_server_principal_name in (''+ @LoginName +'') AND 
                            event_time >= ''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@EventStartTime) +''" QUERYOUT ''R:\Test.txt'' -c -T -t ''|'' '

    Print @BCPSQL

    --EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @BCPSQL

END
```

This is the parameters I am using to execute the stored procedure:

```
exec dbo.TEST @LoginName = 'TestUser', @EventStartTime = '2018-01-19 00:00:00'
```

This is the printed @BCPSQL:

```
BCP "SELECT * FROM fn_get_audit_file('R:\Audit\*', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
                            WHERE session_server_principal_name in ('+ @LoginName +') AND 
                            event_time >= '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@EventStartTime) +'" QUERYOUT 'R:\Test.txt' -c -T -t '|'
```

And this is the message printed after executing the BCPSQL script:

[image]

Any ideas as to why it is not outputting the results to a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to put everything on line like this:

```
BCP "SELECT * FROM fn_get_audit_file('R:\Audit\*', DEFAULT, DEFAULT) WHERE session_server_principal_name in ('+ @LoginName +') AND event_time >= '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@EventStartTime) +'" QUERYOUT 'R:\Test.txt' -c -T'
```